# Get all content from a file, including PHP code

Tags: php

I'm making a small CMS for practice. I am using CKEDITOR and is trying to make it avaliable to write something like %contactform% in the text, and then my PHP function will replace it with a contactform.

I've accomplished to replace the text with a form. But now I need the PHP code for the form to send a mail. I'm using file_get_contents(); but it's stripping the php-code.

I've used include(); to get the php-code from another file then and that works for now. I would like to do it with one file tho.

So - can I get all content from a file INCLUDING the php-code?

**UPDATE **

I'll try to explain in another way.

I can create a page in my CMS where I can write a header and some content. In the content I am able to write %contactform%.

When I get the content from the database I am replacing %contactform% with the content from /inserts/contactform.php, using file_get_contents(); where I have the form in HTML and my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo 'Now my form is submitted!';
}

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now I was expecting to retrieve the form AND the php code active. But If I press my submit button in the form it's not firing the php code.

I do **not** wan't to show the php code I want to be able to **use** it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php

Comment: If I get your intention correctly, I think you'll have to try [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/function.eval.php).

Comment: @RayPaseur This just reveals the code?

Comment: @Yoshi I think I'll try to figure out something else. It's like I can't explain what I wan't to do.

Comment: I think we need to see your example code; I may not be understanding the description of the issue - something along the lines of http://sscce.org/

Comment: @RayPaseur I have tried to explain my self, please watch the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have to guess, but from your update, I think you ultimatly end up with a variable, which contains the content from the database with `%contactform%` replaced by `file_get_contents('/inserts/contactform.php')`.

Something like:

```
$contentToOutput = str_replace(
  '%contactform%',
  file_get_contents('/inserts/contactform.php'),
  $contentFromDatabase
);
```

If you `echo` out that variable, it will just send it's content as is. No php will get executed.

Though it's risky in many cases, if you know what you're doing you can use [eval](http://php.net/manual/function.eval.php) to parse the php code. With mixed code like this, you maybe want to do it like the following.

```
ob_start();
eval('; ?>' . $contentToOutput); 
$parsedContent = ob_get_clean();
```

`$parsedContent` should now contain the results after executing the code. You can now send it to the user or handle it whatever way you want to.

Of course you'll have to make sure that whatever is in `$contentToOutput` is valid php code (or a valid mixture of php with php-tags and text).

[Here](https://github.com/symfony/Templating/blob/master/PhpEngine.php) is a link to the symfony *Templating/PhpEngine* class. Have a look at the `evaluate` method to see the above example in real code.

Comment: This actually works. I tho need to ask you something. Why do you write '; ?>' in the eval() function?

Comment: `eval` expects php code, if whatever is in `$contentToOutput` starts with, say, html, it will not be valid php and thus throw an error when executed. Using `'; ?>'` will help to prevent that error.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that clearly, but what I've asked for works now. I just have to make some validating on the content being output through eval.

Answer (score 1):

yes...

```
$content = file_get_contents( 'path to your file' );
```

for printing try

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $content );
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It's not bringing the php-code only the HTML.

Comment: how are you checking the content in your variable? printing in html? try htmlspecialchars to print it.

Comment: @AspiringAqib Ok, then there's nothing else to do then including?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: that's not true, file_get_contents works, don't confuse the others

Comment: I was just joking see my above comment :P

Comment: well, working here though and well, i m a worst programmer why are you asking me?

Comment: @bukfixart Please look at my updated question. If I use htmlspecialchars(); it's just printing the php-code as html, that's not what I wan't. I want the php-code to be active at the "new" place

Comment: okay... this isn't good programming. Just try `eval( ... )`. But remember: "eval is evil"!

Answer (score 0):

From reading the revised question, I think the answer is "You can't get there from here."  Let me try to explain what I think you will encounter.

First, consider the nature of HTTP and the client/server model.  Clients make requests and servers make responses.  Each request is atomic, complete and stateless, and each response is complete and usually instantaneous.  And that is the end of it.  The server disconnects and goes back to "sleep" until the client makes a new request.

Let's say I make a request for a web page.  A PHP script runs and it prepares a response document (HTML, probably) and the server sends the document to my browser.  If the document contains an HTML form, I can submit the form to the URL of the *action=* script.  But when I submit the form, I am making a new request that goes back to the server.

As I understand your design, the plan is to put both the HTML form and the PHP action script into the textarea of the CKeditor at the location of the %contactform% string.  This would be presented to the client who would submit the form back to your server, where it would run the PHP script.  I just don't think that will work, and if you find a way to make it work, you're basically saying, "I will accept external input and run it in PHP." That would represent an unacceptable security exposure for me.

If you can step back from the technical details and just tell us in plain language what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to offer a suggestion about the design pattern.

Comment: It looks like it's the same.

Comment: *File_get_contents() effectively accesses a URL so it runs through the PHP Parser* this is simply not correct.

Comment: Really, Yoshi?  Show me your alternative

Comment: Why, it's simply not correct that `file_get_contents` will parse php code. Have you even tried it before posting that statement?

Comment: Yes, it depends on whether you're reading from a URL or a file.  If reading a URL you'll likely get what the server sends, right?

Comment: Correct, but in that way the sending server runs the code through the php-parser, not the receiving function (e.g. `file_get_contents`).

Comment: Yes, I take your point.  We don't really have a good test case for this question, so I wrote one.  The observed behavior is exactly what you say.